# Yesod: long-polling/shared memory on persistent data

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

For a web service I want to create a long polling endpoint in Yesod which waits until a value on an persistent object has changed. I saw examples of long polling requests with Yesod using SMT and shared memory. Is there any way to bind persistent objects from yesod-persistent to TVars and retrieve them in multiple requests or is there another approach (like looping a thread sleep until the value in the database changed)?